# Trouble copying select rows from one csv to another

Tags: python, csv

I have a massive csv file with global temperature readings. I want to find all of the rows where the country is United States and append those to a new CSV.

```
import csv

country = 'United States'

file_in = 'GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv'
file_out = 'out.csv'
country = 'United States'

with open('GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv', 'rt', encoding="utf8") as f, \
    open(file_out, "a", newline='') as f_output:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
         if country == row[4]:
              csv.writer(f_output).writerows(row)
```

This is what the output csv looks like:
[one char per cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2MMS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `writerows()` to write one row of data. Try using `writerow()` instead.

Also, it is better to instantiate your writer outside the `for` loop once and then use it inside the loop:

```py
writer = csv.writer(f_output)
for row in reader:
    if country == row[4]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That totally solved the issue.